# Remove all scheduled before 17:00 jobs with atrm

Tags: shell-script, at, jobs

I need a shell script that removes all scheduled before 17:00 jobs with the user name as a positional parameter
This is what I tried to do

```
#!/bin/bash
currentTime = ‘date + %k%M’
check_time_tu_run()
{
  tempTime=$1
  if 
    [ $tempTime -gt 000 -a $tempTime -lt 1700];
  then
    for i in `atq | awk '{print $1}'`;do atrm $i;done
  else 
    echo “Action is not in the period of time”
  fi

}

check_time_to_run $currentTime
```

Comment: @StephenKitt

I edited it

Comment: Besides the smart quotes, what happened when you tried to use it? (sample input & output)

Answer (score 1):

1. You're using the wrong quoting around the date command. You're using "curly" single quotes (`‘...’`) instead of backticks (`` `...` ``), but use `$(...)` instead of backticks.
2. You're not allowed spaces around the `=` for a variable assignment
3. The `+` must not be followed by a space.

Use: `currentTime=$( date +%k%M )`

Also the name of the function you *define* (`check_time_tu_run`)
is not the name of the function you *call* (`check_time_to_run`)

There are other errors: paste your code into https://www.shellcheck.net for more assistance.

Comment: Any way you could help me make it work?

Comment: Of course: follow the advice I've already written.